# How to group and select the latest data record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012

The result of my query is like this:

[image]

How do I get only record with `max(tnxdate)` and `sum(total)`?

Like this:

```
total    actbucket  tnxbucket
--------------------------------
4        18+   7-12 m
```

I tried this:

```
select 
    sum(id), tnxbucket, actbucket 
from
    (select 
        *,
        rn = row_number()over(partition by id order by tnxdate desc) from t
    ) x
where 
   x.rn = 1 
group by 
   tnxbucket, actbucket
```

but it gives me like this

```
total  actbucket  tnxbucket
------------------------------
3    18+  18+
1    18+ 7-12
```

I want tnxbucket, actbucket that is with max tnxdate

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @marc for edit.. could you help with the query ?

Comment: Where is the date `20131031` coming from in your desired output? Is that a typo?

Comment: how do you know which value to display from the column tnxbucket ? You have 2 different values currently and only want one. So how is that decided ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : the record with 18 + 7-12 m is choosen because the corresponding tnxdate is maximum ..so actdate,tnxdate is to be choosen..pls help me on this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT t1.total, t1.tnxdate, t2.actbucket, t2.tnxbucket
FROM (SELECT id, SUM(total) as total, MAX(tnxdate) as tnxdate
      FROM table
      GROUP BY id) t1 
        LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.tnxdate  = t2.tnxdate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH cte as
(
  SELECT 
    max(tnxdate) over (partition by id) mx, 
    sum(total) over (partition by id) total,
    actbucket, 
    tnxbucket
  FROM t
)
SELECT TOP 1 
  total, 
  actbucket, 
  tnxbucket 
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
  mx desc,
  tnxbucket desc
```